# "invalid XPath expression" error in Visual Studio 2008 TS

Tags: xslt, xpath, visual-studio-2008

I'm learning XSLT via "Beginning XSLT 2.0 From Novice to Professional". Following the source code from the book, I've tried to compile this in Visual Studio 2008 TS:

```
<xsl:template match="Program">
  <div>
    <p>
      <xsl:if test="@flag">
        <img src="{if (@flag = 'favorite') then 'favorite' else 'interest'}.gif" 
             alt="[{if (@flag = 'favorite') then 'Favorite' else 'Interest'}]" 
             width="20" height="20" />
      </xsl:if>
      <!-- ... -->
    </p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML data is as follows:

```
<Channel>
  <Name>BBC1</Name>
  <Program rating="5" flag="favorite">
    <!-- ... -->
  </Program>
  <!-- ... -->
</Channel>
```

However, when I compile this code I get:

```
'string(if (@flag = 'favorite') then 'favorite' else 'interest')' 
is an invalid XPath expression.
```

I've checked the website of the book looking for an errata, unfortunately this hasn't been covered. Any pointers would be fantastic.

Comment: @Eval_Penguin: Please don't torture yourself by converting `"<"` to `"&lt;"`. Instead you can use the "0101" code format editor button or you can indent code blocks with four spaces. You'll even get free syntax highlighting. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio supports XSLT 1.0.  AFAIK no microsoft product supports Xslt 2.0 yet; XQuery 1.0 in SQL Server is the closest you'll get.

**Edit:**  To be clear, the if..then..else syntax is XPath 2.0, not XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the reason for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Xslt is much more verbose

you should use somehting like this :

```
<img>
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="@flag='favorite'">favorite</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>interest</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution to this problem.

Comment: And this extra verbosity is the reason it's a shame microsoft won't implement XSLT 2.0!